# libldap & dpkg errors

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I seem to have a problem with my install after removing Wine 1.8:

```
[installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 227273 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libldap-2.4-2_2.4.41+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.41+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.41+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/ldap/ldap.conf', which is different from other instances of package libldap-2.4-2:amd64
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.41+dfsg-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of evolution-data-server:
 evolution-data-server depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package evolution-data-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-libs:amd64:
 samba-libs:amd64 depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package samba-libs:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl3:amd64:
 libcurl3:amd64 depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcurl3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl3-gnutls:amd64:
 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libldb1:amd64:
 libldb1:amd64 depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libldb1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-samba:
 python-samba depends on libldb1 (>= 0.9.21); however:
  Package libldb1:amd64 is not configured yet.
 python-samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.17+dfsg-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfolks-eds25:amd64:
 libfolks-eds25:amd64 depends on evolution-data-server (>= 3.2.0); however:
  Package evolution-data-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libfolks-eds25:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-core depends on libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7); however:
  Package libldap-2.4-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of whoopsie:
 whoopsie depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package whoopsie (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.17+dfsg-4ubuntu3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.]
```